# A simple question about Minkowski inquality for sums

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-explanation

This is a part of the proof of minkowski inequality. My doubt is the following:

> why were we able to apply Holder's inequality to the last line?

[image]

We should prove that $$\sum_{j=1}^\infty \lvert\omega_j\rvert^{q(p-1)}=\sum_{j=1}^\infty \lvert\omega_j\rvert^{p}<\infty,$$ that is $\omega_j\in l^q$, but is this true? What am I not considering?

Comment: Hölder's inequality holds also for infinite cases, that is when left side is infinite then right is infinite as well. When right side is infinite inequality is always true, but might not be useful.

Comment: Maybe you missed the definition of $q=p/(p-1)$ so that $1/p+1/q=1$?

Comment: @daw Thanks for your interest, but I don't see what this has to do with what I'm asking, maybe I don't understand what you mean. I would like to know why it is possible to apply Holder's inequality to the last line.

Comment: and I do not understand, what are your doubts about applying Hoelder inequality? Here the inequality is first applied for finite sums $\sum_{j=1}^n$, then the sum containing the $\omega_j$ can be cancelled on the right, the one can do $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @daw Right! I had in sight that the sums were finite. My doubt was that since Holder's inequality had been shown for sequences in $\ell_p$ and in $\ell_q$, I was trying to prove that $\rvert\omega_j \lvert^{p-1}\in\ell_q$. But you pointed out to me that the sums are finite, so we don't have to show anything.